# Input array in array

Tags: html, arrays, input

Is it possible to create an array in an array for inputs?

So:

```
<input type="text" name="array[array[]]" />
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A two dimensional array is an array inside an array.  Many questions like this...

```
<input type="text" name="import[fields][0]" >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 In HTML

    <input type="text" name="import[fields][0]" >
    <input type="text" name="import[fields][1]" >
    <input type="text" name="import[fields][2]" >
 IN PHP
    <?php
    if ( isset($_POST['submit']) )
    {
        print_r($_POST['field']); 
    }
    ?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="field[one][1]" />
<input type="text" name="field[one][2]" />
<input type="text" name="field[one][3]" />
<br /><br />
<input type="text" name="field[two][1]" />
<input type="text" name="field[two][2]" />
<input type="text" name="field[two][3]" />
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```